# Getting extra digit while trying to union two arrays in JAVA

Tags: java

In a task I have I need to union two sets(arrays of integers), but from some reason i'm getting the wrong output...

this is the attributes of the class set:

```
private int []set; 
private int counter;
private int max = 10;
```

this is the constructor I use to get numbers(i needed to use varags because i need to be able to change the number of elements in the set):

```
public Set (int...numbers) {

        set = new int[max];
        counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

            if (!this.isMember(numbers[i])) { 
                this.set[this.counter] = numbers[i];
                this.counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the union method:

```
public Set union (Set setToUnion) {

    Set setToReturn;

    if (this.equals(setToUnion)){
        setToReturn = new Set(setToUnion);
        return setToReturn;
    }

    setToReturn = new Set(this.set);

    for (int i = 0; i < setToUnion.counter; i++) {

        if (!setToReturn.isMember(setToUnion.set[i])) {
            setToReturn.set[setToReturn.counter ] = setToUnion.set[i];
            setToReturn.counter++;
        }
    }
    return setToReturn;
}
```

and if you want to see how the isMember looks so here it is(just checking if some number is a member of other set):

```
public boolean isMember (int n) {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.counter; i++) {

            if (n == this.set[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Now in the program I created two sets like this:

```
Set someSet = new Set(1,2,3,4,5);       
Set anotherSet = new Set(2,6,7,8,9);

Set m = someSet.union(anotherSet);

m.show();
```

but the output I'm getting is (1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,8,9) and i need the same one but without the 0 in the middle...

please help
thanks!

Comment: Where's the union method?

Comment: sorry just chenched it :/ my problem is with the union @ooga

Comment: So the question title is wrong?

Comment: it was, i changed it too, sorry for that guys @DavidWallace

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing some `{}` characters in your code?  In particular, the ones around the second `if` block inside `union`?

Comment: @Gus are you sure?  The constructor looks fine to me, other than the issue of what happens if there are more than 10 things in the array.

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be this line in the union method:

```
setToReturn = new Set(this.set);
```

It should probably be:

```
setToReturn = new Set(this);
```

Why is that causing a problem?
At this point, `this.set` equals `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, which is an int array. Therefore, the following constructor will be called:

```
public Set (int...numbers) { ... }
```

That means all those numbers in the array will be added, including the zeroes. Either you need to truncate the zeroes from the array by doing something like...

```
setToReturn = new Set( Arrays.copyOf( set, counter ) );
```

or have a constructor that accepts a `Set`. That way you can access `counter` to see how many numbers in the array are actually part of the  `Set`. I guessed you already have that constructor, based on another part of the code that calls such a constructor.